# in Typescript how can I set a conditional return type based on a function argument?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Considering this code snippet:

```
interface Options<S extends boolean> {
  limit?: number
  offset?: number
  single?: S
}

const fetchItems = async <T = unknown, S extends boolean = false>(
  collection: string,
  opts: Options<S> = {}
): Promise<S extends true ? T : T[]> => {
  const { data } = await axios.get<{ data: any }>(`/items/${collection}`, {
    params: {
      limit: opts.limit,
      offset: opts.offset,
      single: opts.single,
    },
  })

  return data.data
}
```

if I call this function like this:

```
await fetchItems<{ id: number }>("pages", { single: true })
```

I get the error "Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'".

How can I make `S` infer the type based on the value passed in the options argument?

Comment: You should also give the second generic parameter: ```await fetchItems<{ id: number }, true>("pages", { single: true })```. Otherwise TS will take the given default of ```false``` and this results in your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function inference is all or nothing. If you specify a type argument explicitly, typescript will not infer the other ones (the default will be used instead)

You could use function currying to have some parameters specified and some inferred, however in this case I would recommend using function overloads:

```
async function fetchItems <T = unknown>(collection: string, opts: Options<true> & { single: true }): Promise<T>
async function fetchItems <T = unknown>(collection: string, opts?: Options<false>): Promise<T[]>
async function fetchItems <T = unknown>(collection: string, opts: Options<boolean> = {}): Promise<T| T[]> {
  //...
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Hz9LIACZSzAfOWVZXq7W9A2rOCW3A203B3xh4WAMwTqfzYKzmuyOvQRsrtedyOh86aTpAA)

Answer (score 0):

you need explict type parameter S as true, like

```js
await fetchItems<{ id: number }, true>("pages", { single: true })
```

Comment: that was what I wanted to avoid